# AngularJS ng-repeat setting default select value

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
$scope.activities =
    [
        { id: 1, type: "DROPDOWN_MENU", name: "Dropdown Menu" },
        { id: 2, type: "HORIZONTAL_BAR", name: "Horizontal Bar" }
    ];

<select data-ng-model="engineer.currentActivity" data-ng-options="a.name for a in activities">                
</select>
```

Using the above I am able to create a select box with 3 values, a blank one and then dropdown menu and horizontal bar.

I would like to set Horizontal Bar as my default and cannot see how to do this.

Help would be great

Comment: BTW, if you are going to end up pulling `activities` from the server, and you need to hydrate the selected option, you want to look into `track by` expressions inside the `ng-options` expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the controller, just add a line to setup the initial selection:

```
$scope.activities =
    [
        { id: 1, type: "DROPDOWN_MENU", name: "Dropdown Menu" },
        { id: 2, type: "HORIZONTAL_BAR", name: "Horizontal Bar" }
    ];

$scope.engineer = {}; // if needed
$scope.engineer.currentActivity = $scope.activities[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

In your angular controller:

```
$scope.activities = [
    { id: 1, type: "DROPDOWN_MENU", name: "Dropdown Menu" },
    { id: 2, type: "HORIZONTAL_BAR", name: "Horizontal Bar" }
];
$scope.activity = $scope.activities[1]; //Bind 2nd activity to the model.
```

In the HTML:

```
<select ng-model="activity" 
    ng-options="activity as activity.name for activity in activities">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97ks4/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-init` [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit)

```
ng-init="engineer.currentActivity = options[1]"
```